# How to Bind two Check boxes to one Button

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I have two check-boxes: Notice of Arbitration Withdrawal & Settlement and Waiver. When notice of arbitration is checked, I am able to print it, but when settlement and waiver is checked, the print report button does nothing. How do I go about being able to bind both check-boxes to the command I have here at the bottom since I can not have to gets within the one GetArbitrationCommand.

```
 public ICommand GetArbitrationCommand
        {
            get { return new RelayCommand(c => OnPrintArbitrationWithdrawal()); } 

        }



<CheckBox Content="Notice of Arbitration Withdrawl" VerticalAlignment="Center" IsChecked="{Binding  IsNoticeofArbitrationWithdrawal, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
<CheckBox Content="Settlement and Waiver" VerticalAlignment="Center" IsChecked="{Binding  IsSettlementandWaiver, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

[image]

Comment: Please, do not post code as images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that you're using the checkboxes to indicate whether a specific portion of your report is to be printed. In the method that is called by your command, you can easily access the properties that these checkboxes are bound to.

```
private void OnPrintArbitrationWithdrawal()
{
    if (IsNoticeofArbitrationWithdrawal)
        // Print Notice of Arbitration Withdrawal

    if (IsSettlementandWaiver)
        // Print Settlement and Waiver
}
```

If I've missed the mark, you may need to edit your question. I'm finding it difficult to understand what you're asking and I suspect others will have the same problem.